# Sessions or cookies not passed through iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iframe, cookies

I am trying to pass data between a iframe and my main page but the sessions aren't passed at all nor cookies.
I can't pass it as queries since I don't want to reload the page like that.
Mostly I wanted to get data from iframe though the example shows otherwise but its just easier to understand like this.

Heres my main page code behind:

```
 // Session["Page"] = GetCurrentPageName(); I tried this too
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Page", GetCurrentPageName())); //Page name is an example   
         SignPad = new LiteralControl("<iframe border='0' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='true' id='" + ((Control)sender).ID + "frame"  name='embeddedFrame' runat=server src='www.website.com/SignPad.aspx"></iframe>");
        ((Control)sender).Parent.Controls.Add(SignPad);
```

And here is my iFrame code behind:

```
protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("TheSignature",Request.Form["TheData"]));
    Response.Redirect(Request.Cookies["Page"].Value);
}
```

Anyway there is just no response.
Am I being stupid or is there some sort of restriction?

Comment: The obvious first question is are the iframe and main page on the same domain?

Comment: Yea, I aint that silly. They are on the same domain

Comment: Solved. When opening an iframe don't use the full url, only the actual name, otherwise it thinks you are on the same domain. Sorry for the whole question.

Comment: sadly some people are that silly and its always worth checking before looking too hard at other stuff. As it is the question didn't seem silly at all given the answer. I'd put that in as an answer (self answered questions are fine) since I think that it has some value.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new iFrame note that writing the full url address as the source will make it handle as if its not on the same domain.
As a solution write only the name of the page for the source.

For more information on where the sessions are stored refer to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx